# Loading the built-in jQuery in Joomla 4 if it does not exist

Tags: php, jquery, joomla-4

Tell me please.  How to load jQuery in Joomla 4 if it has not been loaded yet?

Comment: Your question is clear, but has been flagged by the system as being low-quality due to its length.  Might you [edit] your question to include attempts that you've made and relevant online resources that are on-topic?  I like to upvote questions, but my personal criteria requires that effort/research is demonstrated in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lodder](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/168/lodder) answer is certainly useful, but not what I wanted to see. The correct loading of the embedded jquery looks like this.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->useScript('jquery');
```

This will work if jquery has not been loaded before.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to load it like so:

```
Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper::_('jquery.framework');
```

Else, if you're using Joomla's Web Asset Manager, then you can define it as a dependency in your JSON object:

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "type": "script",
  "uri": "com_mycomponent/script.min.js",
  "dependencies": [
    "jquery"
  ]
},
```